# Is it possible to use 2 different SSD with different OS on the same computer without any data loss?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ssd, multi-boot

I have a laptop, actually I was using a **SSD with Ubuntu**, and I had an other hard-drive emplacement empty, so I was wondering as I already have a **SSD with Windows** already functionnal and installed on it:

- Can I put both SSD into my laptop and choose on which one to boot easily ?
- Is there any risks that I break or loose any data on Ubuntu while using the Windows SSD or or the opposite ?

*note: both SSD already have they respective OS installed. I do not want to use any third-party software*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dual-boot two separate hard drives with OS already installed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1159354/how-to-dual-boot-two-separate-hard-drives-with-os-already-installed)

Comment: There are always risks. Properly configured Ubuntu should not try to do anything to the Windows drive, and Windows shouldn't even be able to read the Ubuntu drive.

Comment: @music2myear This shouldn't happen, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition)