# In order to dual boot, is it necessary to install the second OS in the same drive as the primary Os?

Tags: windows, ssd, kali-linux, dualboot

So, basically i was thinking to Dual boot linux and windows ( windows pre installed)... But one question kept bugging me, and you might ask why it's a problem, since my Windows is installed in an Ssd, which has about a few Gigabytes left, Which forces me to chose another drive for linux, is it okay?.. Will it still dual boot, if i install it on the other drive, rather than installing it in the ssd?

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1159354/how-to-dual-boot-two-separate-hard-drives-with-os-already-installed

Comment: In the past, Windows needed to be installed on the boot disk whereas at least some Linux boot loaders didn't care much where Linux was (i.e. it could be on a separate disk). Not sure how it works currently but it would be a bit suprising if it has changed much, even with ex. UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and its arguably more ideal) to have the OS's on different drives.  You have not advised what boot mechanism you are using (MBR or uefi) but both have the capacity to boot from more then 1 drive.